# how to count number of files in a particular directory, without scanning subfolders in python

Tags: python

I tried like;

```
 files = os.listdir(file_path)
    print(len(files)) <--gets counts of all files in subdirctory too
 for f in files:
  if (f.endswith('.xlsx')):
    print(count of *.clxs files)
```

I need only excel files count in the root directory.How to do that in python?

Comment: `os.listdir` does not "scan" subdirectories. Unless you mean that it returns the names of subdirectories?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this

```
xslx_files=[]
files = os.listdir(file_path)
    print(len(files)) <--gets counts of all files in subdirctory too
 for f in files:
  if (f.endswith('.xlsx')):
    xslx_files.append(f)
print(len(xslx_files))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a version of Python >=3.4 you can use [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html)

```
base_path = pathlib.Path(file_path)
num_spreadsheets = len(list(base_path.glob('*.xlsx')))
```

Answer (score 0):

The first element of fileCounts is the count number of root files, and others are that of sub-directories:

```
import os
fileCounts=[]
for root,dirs,files in os.walk(file_path,topdown=True):
  xlsxFiles=[]
  for f in files:
    if f.endswith(".xlsx"):
      xlsxFiles.append(f)
  fileCounts.append(len(xlsxFiles))
print(fileCounts[0])
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import os
for file in os.listdir("/mydir"):
    if file.endswith(".xlsx"):
        print(os.path.join("/mydir", file))
```